# Can a lower gauge jumper be connected to a high amperage circuit as long as it is going to an appropriate sized breaker?

Tags: dc, fuses, circuit-protection, circuit-breaker, gauge

The 14 AWG wire is connected to an appropriate sized circuit breaker to prevent that run of wire from drawing too many amps; however, my concerns would be that the 2/0 cable being in such close proximity to the 14 AWG could dissipate enough heat to melt the 14 AWG.

Unfortunately the circuit logic needs to be pretty close to this, and if the 14 AWG is not sufficient would the easiest solution be to use a 2/0 cable to the line side of the breaker?

This is a 24 VDC circuit.

Thanks!

[image: circuit in question]

Edit:

Not a new circuit like above, but I'd imagine this is equally problematic? Or is the stark difference between a 14 AWG and 2/0 the MAIN issue? Is there an appropriate AWG delta that is acceptable?
[image]

Comment: What is 2/0 cable?

Comment: @Andy aka: 2/0 is AWG wire size 00.

Comment: Sorry, had a toss up which way you guys would prefer I wrote that!

Comment: The problem with your 1st diagram is that the #14 wire is being protected by a 500A fuse. So if a fault develops on that length of wire between the 2/0 and the 15A breaker then your little #14 wire will probably turn bright red and catch fire...

Comment: @brhans Yes, but this is equally an issue in the second diagram right? Albeit a little less since that case it is a 2 AWG and a 6 AWG, but neither of those can handle 500 A.

Answer (score 1):

AWG 14 on the source side of the circuit breaker is somewhat problematic. In AC power distribution, the circuit breakers would be connected directly to a bus bar in a steel distribution box that is designed for the purpose.

In any case, 2/0 is used because it is the proper size to limit the wire temperature to the insulation rating, no higher than the 14 AWG carrying its rated current. However, to make a proper connection, you probably need to connect the 2/0 to a short bus bar using a proper terminal for the wire size. Then several wire of various sizes can be connected to the bus bar in a similar manner. The connection area needs to be well protected from accidental contact and short circuit in the connection area.

The main issues are:

1. Wire on the load side of the fuse that is smaller than 2/0 is not protected, so must be as short as possible.
2. Unprotected wire and connection points must be in an appropriate enclosure.
3. Breaker input wire size must not exceed the maximum specified by the breaker manufacturer.
4. Suitable method must be used for connecting multiple wires together. For connecting 2/0 to smaller wires, that may be limited to bus bar.

Comment: Bus bars eh. Yeah we do not use those very often at this company from what I've seen, but sounds like we definitely should be. I've added another circuit which to me would be equally problematic. Or would you say the 2/0 vs 14 AWG size difference is the main issue? Whereas 6 AWG vs 2/0 is a little more acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than spitballing the design here, y'all should really be following the relevant design codes for your jurisdiction (or rather, the ones you wish to sell into).  So the EU design spec, UL White Book, etc.

I don't know why you think 2/0 wire is good for 500A, but I don't have access to the White Book standards.  Under NEC rules for *in-wall wiring*,  2/0 aluminum is 150A @ 90 degrees C (or if using copper for some reason, 195A @ 90C).   Outdoor overhead-lines are more generous: are 235A and 300A respectively.

If the 2/0 wire has very-high-temperature insulation, then presumably the #14 wire has the same stuff.  With or without that, they're going to melt about the same time if the wires are the same insulation type.  However if wires are melting, the wires are far too small for the job.

You may have heard that Code relaxes the rules for low-voltage wires. Relaxes, sure... but not "throws out the window".

Bus bars can be used; in fact many bus bars have holes directly drilled into them to mount wires; a side-drilled setscrew then clamps the wires. Common service panel "ground bars" are a good example.  None of them are rated for 500A.

If your power requirements are appropriate to 2/0 wire, but you are going 500A for startup surge, don't.  Most circuit breakers already factor for startup surge by having a tolerant "trip curve". That's the only reason your air conditioner doesn't trip the breaker half the time it starts up.  You can't use *most* residential circuit breakers with DC, but you can with **Square D QO,** which is specifically listed for DC up to 48V, normal trips of 15-200A, and interrupting rating of 10-22 kiloamps.  Who knows, maybe Home Depot has your distribution solution sitting in stock for under $100.